# Port 8080 not visible while doing netstat?

Tags: windows-server-2003, tomcat, port, localhost, netstat

While trying to run Tomcat on my Windows 2003 OS, I am noticing that the server is not running but at the same time it is not throwing any exceptions on the console. My first hunch was that the server configs are not picking up port 8080 or maybe that port is already in use.

When I did a netstat -an, a bunch of ports showed up but 8080 wasn't one of them. I don't have a firewall running so there is no question of the firewall blocking the port. Does anybody know why would my port 8080 disappear?

Comment: Ports don't "disappear" unless a process that is using the port terminates.  If nothing's using the port then the open port won't be established and you won't see it in netstat.  What http server are you using?  Apache? IIS?

Comment: @squillman - I am using Apache.

Comment: is Apache running?

Comment: @squillman - Yes. Restarting the machine somehow fixed things. I am assuming Apache was holding on to the port. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've restarted the machine - sometimes Apache can hold onto the port.